# Import from a parent's parent package (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

The following is my folder structure:

```
/experiments
    /experiment_1
    /experiment_2
    /experiment_3
        /src
           /sample.py
helper.py
```

All experiments share some code, which I have exported into `helper.py`. Now I'm trying to import a function from `helper.py` into `sample.py`:

```
from ...helper import my_function
```

and I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Please note that I have tried many solutions offered here, but none worked.

Comment: is the folder containing helper.py a package?

Comment: Not all folders are packages. A package is a special folder accessible from the Python path.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4383571/18159997

Comment: @Avi Thanks, it solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

create a `__init__.py` file in your parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

The above question is related to

[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

The solution is to add the following lines in the `sample.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'path-to-experiments')

from helper import get_json
```